# Best way to test Android app in Eclipse simulator emulating different Screen devices

Tags: android, eclipse

I found out the hard way that in certain cases it is much better to define the screen layout in two different xml files rather than trying to write one univeral xml suitable for all screen specs.

- normal 640dp x 480dp in  -> **layout** folder
- small 470dp x 320dp separately in -> **layout-small** folder

While testing works well with different Android real phones I would like to also test emulating in simulator. For example I found that the normal layout works on a Samsung Galaxy but not on HTC (having the same screen dimensions -  I think).

**Is there a reliable way to test the layout in emulation mode for specific phones? How and where do I define the settings?**

ps when defining the xml there are the options for different screens on top of the window - however in many cases this does not work and/or is not reliable (eg when there is text in a textfield) - and it's only for editing not for simulation.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows and have installed the Android SDK you should see a "Android SDK Tools">"SDK Manager" in start menu. There you can edit screen resolutions of all emulators (AVD's) that you have installed. And you can create new ones too. You should be able to select any of these in Eclipse's launch-menu.

Comment: I saw that and tried it - but there is no specific Android phone - I would like to specifically test HTC since my app looked different on this HTC compared to the Samsung Galaxy. And I don't really know all the setting values for the phones.

Comment: Ok. I haven't seen any database of the AVD setting for different phones. Nettuts listed a few at least: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say what the problem is you're having - you can't really 'simulate' an HTC phone in the emulator because you aren't running SENSE on that emulator?

I also think you might be misunderstanding or assuming too much in terms of what the layout-[resources] mean...

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Note the 'at least' bit.

The HTC Wildfire is 320x480 - the HTC Desire is 480x800 - not that they're different 'ratios' - something the layout isn't going to be able to get around for you...